# Java: Returning user input

Tags: java, constructor

Having an issue receiving the "Just Tax." Program compiles, will not calculate sales tax on output - simply returns a "0." The "Sale" method (not within listed code) will acknowledge and print the amount of the sale, however. Not sure what I'm doing incorrectly. Thanks!

```
  //...
  Purchase saleAmount = new Purchase();

  //...

  System.out.println("Please enter a positive (+) number for the sale amount: $");
  double saleAmt = input.nextDouble();
  saleAmount.setSale(saleAmt);

  //...

  System.out.println("The 5% tax applied is: " + saleAmount.getJustTax());

public class Purchase
 //all data types have been declared
 final double SALES_TAX = 0.05;
{
  //Initial Sale Cost
  public double getSale()
{
  return sale;
}

  public void setSale(double amount)
{
  amount = sale;
}

//Get Just Sales Tax
  public double getJustTax()
{
  return justTax;
}
  public void setJustTax(double sale)
{
  justTax = (sale * SALES_TAX);
}
```

}

Comment: did you make a call to `setJustTax()` to calculate `justTax`?

Answer (score 1):

The assignment in your `setSale` method is backwards.  Currently, it assigns whatever is in `sale` to your local variable `amount`.

Change

```
public void setSale(double amount)
{
  amount = sale;
}
```

to

```
public void setSale(double amount)
{
  sale = amount;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public void setSale(double amount)
{
   amount = sale;
}
```

This is causing the issue. What you're currently doing is taking the method argument and assigning your `sale` variable to it. (I cannot see it in the code however).

```
public void setJustTax(double sale)
{
    justTax = (sale * SALES_TAX);
}
```

This means when the above code is called, `sale` still has no value to it and I'll guess that sale is instantiated with `0`.